# In Django how to avoid boilerplate code for getting model instance by pk in a view

Tags: python, django

Here is example code:

```
def someview(request):
    try:
        instance = SomeModel.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('id'))
    except SomeModel.DoesNotExist:
        instance = None
    except ValueError:
        # This error may occur if user manually enter invalid (non-integer)
        # id value (intentionally or not) in a browser address bar, e.g.
        # http://example.com/?id=2_foo instead of http://example.com/?id=2
        # This raises ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2_'
        instance = None
    ...
```

Is there a best practice to get a model instance by pk without writing this boilerplate code over and over? Should I use some predefined shortcut in Django or just roll my own?

I was sure that I should use Django's DetailView or SingleObjectMixin but curiously enough it doesn't handle the ValueError exception from my example https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L50 
Is it implied that I have to specify correct integer regexp for pk kwarg in urlconf? Ok, likely. But what if I get pk from request querystring?

**UPD** I have special logic to do with instance either it's None or not.

Comment: If the object doesn't exist what do you want to do? raise 404 or just do some other logic with instance=`None`

Comment: This is precisely where class based views shine.

Comment: Just to make sure you will notice, you can overwrite get_object method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use Django's built in shorcut [`get_object_or_404()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) that it's designed for this specifically. That function will raise an `Http404` exception in case the object doesn't exist. If you want to get `None` instead of raising the exception, you can create a helper function to accomplish it very easily:

```
def get_object_or_none(klass, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return get_object_or_404(klass, *args, **kwargs)
    except Http404:
        return None
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't handle ValueError in case of incorrect input.

Comment: You can handle it yourself then inside the helper function. If you need a tailored behavior, and `get_object_or_404` doesn't suit your needs just forget about it. Just create a function with its same signature (which is very handy) and factorize all the boilerplate code into it. You'll end up with a helper function tailored to your needs :)

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your try/except block can be simplified by using [django-annoying](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying):

```
from annoying.functions import get_object_or_None

instance = get_object_or_None(SomeModel, id=request.GET.get('id'))
```

FYI, you can also just extract `get_object_or_None` from the package (see [source](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying/blob/develop/annoying/functions.py)).

Answer (score 1):

There are many generic class based views that might be helpful, in your case [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) could work.

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class SomeModelDetailView(DetailView):
     model = SomeModel
```

You can overwrite [get_object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method to change default behaviour.

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return SomeModel.objects.get(pk=self.get_pk())
```

And lastly if object is none you should probably display custom 404 page.